# Cursor switching default/progress on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cursor, mouse-cursor

Recently the cursor started been like this:

[image: Cursor GIF image]

Changing the resolution of the screen or switching cursor type don't solve the problem.

It only happens at the default cursor, hovering a link (cursor pointer) or placing the cursor in text fields (cursor text) the cursor acts normally.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your mousecursor constantly changes to a load in background cursor, this usually means you have a virus or malware running in the background.

Your first thing would be to scan your computer for virusses and malware.

If they don't yield any results, look for other applications running in the background that are taking up system resources.

Comment: Yeah, it was a malware running in the background, the antivirus was expired too. Thanks for your fast response :)